# What promises do return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Consider the following code:

```
var d1=$.Deferred();
var d2=$.Deferred();
d1.resolve();
d2.reject();
var p1=d1.promise();
var p2=d2.promise();
p1.then(function () {
    console.log('promiseOne resolved');
    return p2;
}).then(function () {
    console.log('promiseTwo resolved');
    }, function() {
    console.log('promiseTwo rejected'); });
```

where I am getting the results:

```
promiseOne resolved
promiseTwo rejected
```

My query is which **promise** do we have as caller object **for the second .then** method? To be more specific; if we had:

```
var x=p1.then(function () {
    console.log('promiseOne resolved');
    return p2;
})
```

it is that `x!=p2` and that because **.then** returns a new `jQuery.Deferred().promise()` object. However, in which way p2 affects x? Does the **new promise x** gets only the **value of p2.state()**?

Comment: I think so, yes - as the onFulfilled function returns a promise, the state of `x` "adopts" the state of p2 - note, Promises in jQuery prior to 1.8 (i.e. what is used on this page)  does **not** work that way, it's broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `then` does return a new promise (`x`) that resolves to the result of the callback - and if that result (`p2`) is a promise its state will get adopted so that `x` fulfills when `p2` fulfills and rejects when `p2` rejects. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) and maybe read the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/).